# Get $curauth level

Tags: author-template

I am trying to get the user level of the author that is displayed on an author page (not the current user that is logged in, but the user that is presented on the current author page that I am viewing)

I am using this code

```
<?
get_currentuserinfo() ;
global $user_level;
if ($user_level >= 4) {
     include (TEMPLATEPATH . '/author_1.php');
} else {
    include (TEMPLATEPATH .'/author_2.php');
}
?>
```

I tried to replace $user with $curauth but still no results, it is showing only one template for both.
 Any ideas?

thank you

Comment: Levels have been deprecated years ago, they are mostly meaningless nowadays. Why do you need them?

Comment: simply because I need to have two author pages, based on user level/role

Answer (score 3, accepted):

toscho is correct. User levels have been deprecated for a long time now. However, the following will get you the available information about the author of the posts on an author archive page.

```
$author = get_queried_object();
var_dump($author);
```

In that dump you should see everything you need, but use the `role` not the user level-- look in `$author->roles`. For example:

```
$author = get_queried_object();
$allowed = array('author','editor','administrator');
$roles = array_intersect($author->roles,$allowed);
if (!empty($roles)) {
  include (TEMPLATEPATH . '/author_1.php');
} else {
  include (TEMPLATEPATH .'/author_2.php');
}
```

You should also almost certainly be using [`get_template_part`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_template_part) instead of `include`.

Comment: thanks, but I'm not sure why I should look there. I do not need to see the role, I just need to redirect to the correct author template based on the author's role.

Comment: I do not know how to use it for what I need.

Comment: The code in your opening post is about 90% there. I will expand the answer a later.

Comment: it actually worked with iclude. using get_template_part breaks some code on the template. thank you for your help, much appreciated!

Comment: `get_template_part` should not break code. At its heart is just an `include`. You probably have a variable scope problem.