# Redirect to correct author template based on author role

Tags: author, author-template

I have two author templates, one for normal users and one for special users. Special users are those with user role 'special', so when someone wants to view their author page, they need to use the template author_special.php
 so, if the author we are about to see (for instance, example.com/author/whatever) has the role 'special' the template used will be author_special.php, if the role is not 'special' the template used should be author_normal.php

I tried this in author.php, but it won't work:

```
<?php
if ($author_roles == 'special') {
     include (TEMPLATEPATH . '/author_special.php');
} else {
    include (TEMPLATEPATH .'/author_normal.php');
}
?>
```

What should I do?

thanks

Comment: This looks basically like the same problem you have described here: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/124335/get-curauth-level

Comment: it is the same problem, but I understood I have to explain it better, seems I got answers that I do not know how to use, and they do not solve what I needed.

Comment: Edit and expand on your original question rather than open a new, nearly duplicate question.

Comment: the first question was wrong in the first place. it seems here you can only get answers like yours, that are not related to the actual question, and not at all helpful. You comment is nearly duplicate too.